# Use of bounded predicates

Tags: generics, java-8, predicate

I wonder why this code even compiles. Because here what we have is a `Predicate` which its type could be **String or any of its super type**. Obviously, `length()` is not available in Object class *which is suitable for this predicate*.

```
Predicate<? super String> predicate = s -> s.length() > 3;
Stream.of("cat", "bat", "rat", "doggy").filter(predicate).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Can anyone describe a situation where we must need these type of a bounded type predicate?

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java

Comment: If you'd have read the accepted answer then you would get your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`Stream.of(T t...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...-) returns a `Stream<T>` and you are putting in 4 `String`s, the output of `Stream.of("cat", "bat", "rat", "doggy")` will be a `Stream<String>`.

After that, it's only logical that a `Predicate<? super String>` can be used to filter a `Stream<String>`. Were you to create a list that contains strings and numbers, but is typed to be `List<String>` (for instance, through this bit of code...)

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("cat");
    list.add("bat");
    list.add("rat");
    list.add("doggy");

    List list2 = list;
    list2.add(1);
```

Then

```
list.stream().filter(predicate).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Will throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime when it hits the Integer.

---

As for a situation where you'd want to use `? super Something`, you can read the answer to the question [@Flown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931784/use-of-bounded-predicates#comment65219539_38931784) linked earlier: [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)